# How to combine `vsplit` `term` and `cd` current directory?

Tags: neovim

While using Neovim, I love `:term` very much.

Most of the time, I do the following steps:

1. `vsplit` to open a vertical window.
2. `:term` in the new window to enter terminal.
3. `$ cd CURRENT_PATH` in the shell.

I was wondering if maybe I could combine them all in one vim command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Vim, the `|` character is used as a command separator, making it equivalent to the semicolon in the Unix shell.  Furthermore, the full syntax to the `:term` command is as follows:

```
:te[rminal][!] {cmd}
```

Therefore, I believe the following command should do the trick:

```
:let CP=expand('%:p:h') | vsplit | exec ':term "cd ' .CP .'"'
```

I do not have Neovim installed, however, so am unable to test this command at the moment.

Comment: `:vsplit | term` works, but `:vsplit | term "cd CURRENT_PATH"` doesn't. I know that `:echo expand('%:p')` will show the current path, I want to know how to make it as the path in the new termianl.

Comment: Maybe that's because I'm using fish shell, I will tried to figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: @liweijian I was erroneously treating CURRENT_PATH as a sort of dummy variable. I guess I didn't fully understand what we were trying to accomplish. I have updated my answer. I think you might have better luck with the new command I have proposed  (though it now feels a bit hacky).